# convert amount to rupees and paise in words format in c#

Tags: c#, windows

I have windows application in which i need to convert amount entered in text-box into the words in ruppes and paise format.
for e.g **My amount is `2356.54` then it should display `two thousand three hundred fifty six ruppes and fifty four paise only`** however, i have code that convert amt to words but i am not able to show `paise`.i am including my code for reference purpose.

```
private void btntowords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           MessageBox.Show( words(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text)));
        }

        public string words(int numbers)
        {
            int number = numbers;

            if (number == 0) return "Zero";
            if (number == -2147483648) return "Minus Two Hundred and Fourteen Crore Seventy Four Lakh Eighty Three Thousand Six Hundred and Forty Eight";
            int[] num = new int[4];
            int first = 0;
            int u, h, t;
            System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            if (number < 0)
            {
                sb.Append("Minus ");
                number = -number;
            }
            string[] words0 = {"" ,"One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ",
"Five " ,"Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine "};
            string[] words1 = {"Ten ", "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ",
"Fifteen ","Sixteen ","Seventeen ","Eighteen ", "Nineteen "};
            string[] words2 = {"Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ",
"Seventy ","Eighty ", "Ninety "};
            string[] words3 = { "Thousand ", "Lakh ", "Crore " };
            num[0] = number % 1000; // units
            num[1] = number / 1000;
            num[2] = number / 100000;
            num[1] = num[1] - 100 * num[2]; // thousands
            num[3] = number / 10000000; // crores
            num[2] = num[2] - 100 * num[3]; // lakhs
            for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (num[i] != 0)
                {
                    first = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            for (int i = first; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (num[i] == 0) continue;
                u = num[i] % 10; // ones
                t = num[i] / 10;
                h = num[i] / 100; // hundreds
                t = t - 10 * h; // tens
                if (h > 0) sb.Append(words0[h] + "Hundred ");
                if (u > 0 || t > 0)
                {
                    if (h > 0 || i == 0) sb.Append("and ");
                    if (t == 0)
                        sb.Append(words0[u]);
                    else if (t == 1)
                        sb.Append(words1[u]);
                    else
                        sb.Append(words2[t - 2] + words0[u]);
                }
                if (i != 0) sb.Append(words3[i - 1]);
            }
            return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
        }
```

It should not show pasie if it has amount like this `2356.00`
so i have tried by many ways to get `paise` but not succeed. i have tried ggogle but not getting exactly what i want.

Comment: I think its better to change `if (h > 0 || i == 0) sb.Append("and ");`  to `if (h != 0 && i == 0) sb.Append("and ");` . Because when conversting 99 to words ,class returning " and ninety-nine".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to separate the decimal number and get two separate values one before decimal place and one after it. For example in 56.2 you get 56 separately and 2 separately and call you words() function for both of them. You'll get two strings one "Fifty six" and second "two". You can join these strings to say "Fifty six rupee 2 paisas".

Answer (score 0):

how to use : string Words = MoneyConvFn(Amount.ToString());

```
  public static string MoneyConvFn(string MVal)
  {
      string TxtMon = MVal;
      string iout = "";

      if (TxtMon.Trim().Length > 18)
      {
          iout = "Maximum 18 digits only Allowed";
      }
      else
      {
          iout = NToW(TxtMon.Trim());
      }

      return iout;
  }


  public static string NToW(string ParaNum)
  {

      if (ParaNum.Length > 18)
      {
          return "Maximum 18 digits only Allowed";
      }
      decimal a1 = Convert.ToDecimal(ParaNum);
      Int64 a2 = (Int64)decimal.Floor(a1);
      decimal a3 = a1 - a2;
      if (a2.ToString().Length > 18)
      {
          return "Maximum 18 digits only Allowed";
      }

      Int64 Part1 = default(Int64);
      Int64 Part2 = default(Int64);
      Int64 Part3 = default(Int64);
      Int64 TempV1 = default(Int64);
      Int64 TempV2 = default(Int64);
      TempV1 = TempV2 = Part1 = Part2 = Part3 = 0;
      Int64 Fr = (Int64)(a3 * 100);
      TempV1 = a2;

      TempV2 = (Int64)decimal.Floor(TempV1 / 10000000);
      Part1 = TempV1 - TempV2 * 10000000;
      TempV1 = TempV2;

      if (TempV1 >= 10000000)
      {
          TempV2 = (Int64)decimal.Floor(TempV1 / 10000000);
          Part2 = TempV1 - TempV2 * 10000000;
          TempV1 = TempV2;
      }
      else
      {
          Part2 = TempV1;
          TempV1 = 0;
      }

      if (TempV1 >= 10000000)
      {
          TempV2 = (Int64)decimal.Floor(TempV1 / 10000000);
          Part3 = TempV1 - TempV2 * 10000000;
          TempV1 = TempV2;
      }
      else
      {
          Part3 = TempV1;
          TempV1 = 0;
      }
      if (TempV1 >= 10000000)
      {
          return "Rupees Conversion Error: Number exceeds the Length 21 digits";
      }

      string NName = "";
      int ln = NName.Trim().Length;

      if (Part3 > 0)
      {
          NName = NName.Trim() + NToWConv(Part3.ToString()) + " Crore Crore ";
      }
      if (Part2 > 0)
      {
          if (Part2 == 1)
          {
              NName = NName.Trim() + "" + NToWConv(Part2.ToString()) + " Crore ";
          }
          else
          {
              NName = NName.Trim() + "" + NToWConv(Part2.ToString()) + " Crores ";
          }
      }
      if (Part1 > 0)
      {
          NName = NName.Trim() + "" + NToWConv(Part1.ToString());
      }
      if (NName.Trim().Length > 0)
      {
          NName = " " + NName;
          //NName = "Rupees " + NName;
      }
      if (Fr > 0)
      {
          if (NName.Trim().Length > 0)
          {
              NName = NName.Trim() + " And " + NToWConv(Fr.ToString()) + " Paise";
          }
          else
          {
              NName = NToWConv(Fr.ToString()) + " Paise";
          }
      }
      if (NName.Trim().Length > 0)
      {
          NName = NName + " Rupees Only";
      }
      return NName;
  }

  private static string NToWConv(String aaa)
  {
      Int64[] no = new Int64[10];
      int k = 0;
      string a = "";
      k = aaa.Length;
      for (int j = 0; j <= 6; j++)
      {
          if (k > 0)
          {
              no[j] = Convert.ToInt64(aaa.Substring(k - 1, 1));
          }
          else
          {
              no[j] = 0;
          }
          k = k - 1;
      }

      a = a + sxsn(no[6], no[5]);
      a = a + frfv(no[4], no[3]);
      a = a + three(no[2]);

      if (a.Trim().Length > 0)
      {
          if (no[1] != 0 || no[0] != 0)
          {
              a = a + " And ";
          }
      }

      a = a + two(no[1], no[0]);
      if (no[1] != 1)
      {
          a = a + One(no[0]);
      }
      return a;
  }

  private static string sxsn(Int64 x, Int64 y)
  {
      if (x == 0 && y == 0)
      {
          return "";
      }
      else
      {
          if (x != 0)
          {
              if (x != 1)
              {
                  return two(x, y) + One(y) + " Lakhs ";
              }
              else
              {
                  return two(x, y) + " Lakhs ";
              }
          }
          else
          {
              return One(y) + " Lakh ";
          }
      }
  }
  private static string frfv(Int64 x, Int64 y)
  {
      if (x == 0 && y == 0)
      {
          return "";
      }
      else
      {
          if (x != 0)
          {
              if (x != 1)
              {
                  return two(x, y) + One(y) + " Thousand ";
              }
              else
              {
                  return two(x, y) + " Thousand ";
              }
          }
          else
          {
              return One(y) + " Thousand ";
          }
      }
  }


  private static string three(Int64 x)
  {
      if (x != 0)
      {
          //to avoid empty hundred for 1000
          string xx = One(x) + " Hundred ";
          return xx;
      }
      else
      {
          return "";
      }
  }


  private static string two(Int64 x, Int64 y)
  {
      switch (x)
      {
          case 1:
              switch (y)
              {
                  case 0:
                      return "Ten";
                  case 1:
                      return "Eleven";
                  case 2:
                      return "Twelve";
                  case 3:
                      return "Thirteen";
                  case 4:
                      return "Fourteen";
                  case 5:
                      return "Fifteen";
                  case 6:
                      return "Sixteen";
                  case 7:
                      return "Seventeen";
                  case 8:
                      return "Eighteen";
                  case 9:
                      return "Nineteen";
                  default:
                      return "";
              }
              break;
          case 2:
              return "Twenty ";
          case 3:
              return "Thirty ";
          case 4:
              return "Forty ";
          case 5:
              return "Fifty ";
          case 6:
              return "Sixty ";
          case 7:
              return "Seventy ";
          case 8:
              return "Eighty ";
          case 9:
              return "Ninety ";
          default:
              return "";
      }
  }


  private static string One(Int64 x)
  {
      switch (x)
      {
          case 1:
              return "One";
          case 2:
              return "Two";
          case 3:
              return "Three";
          case 4:
              return "Four";
          case 5:
              return "Five";
          case 6:
              return "Six";
          case 7:
              return "Seven";
          case 8:
              return "Eight";
          case 9:
              return "Nine";
          default:

              return "";
      }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need small change in your method. Please find below method

```
public string words(double? numbers, Boolean paisaconversion = false)
    {
        var pointindex = numbers.ToString().IndexOf(".");
        var paisaamt = 0;
        if (pointindex > 0)
         paisaamt = Convert.ToInt32( numbers.ToString().Substring(pointindex + 1, 2));

        int number = Convert.ToInt32( numbers);

        if (number == 0) return "Zero";
        if (number == -2147483648) return "Minus Two Hundred and Fourteen Crore Seventy Four Lakh Eighty Three Thousand Six Hundred and Forty Eight";
        int[] num = new int[4];
        int first = 0;
        int u, h, t;
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        if (number < 0)
        {
            sb.Append("Minus ");
            number = -number;
        }
        string[] words0 = {"" ,"One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ","Five " ,"Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine "};
        string[] words1 = {"Ten ", "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ","Fifteen ","Sixteen ","Seventeen ","Eighteen ", "Nineteen "};
        string[] words2 = {"Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ","Seventy ","Eighty ", "Ninety "};
        string[] words3 = { "Thousand ", "Lakh ", "Crore " };
        num[0] = number % 1000; // units
        num[1] = number / 1000;
        num[2] = number / 100000;
        num[1] = num[1] - 100 * num[2]; // thousands
        num[3] = number / 10000000; // crores
        num[2] = num[2] - 100 * num[3]; // lakhs
        for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
        {
            if (num[i] != 0)
            {
                first = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = first; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (num[i] == 0) continue;
            u = num[i] % 10; // ones
            t = num[i] / 10;
            h = num[i] / 100; // hundreds
            t = t - 10 * h; // tens
            if (h > 0) sb.Append(words0[h] + "Hundred ");
            if (u > 0 || t > 0)
            {
                if (h > 0 || i == 0) sb.Append("and ");
                if (t == 0)
                    sb.Append(words0[u]);
                else if (t == 1)
                    sb.Append(words1[u]);
                else
                    sb.Append(words2[t - 2] + words0[u]);
            }
            if (i != 0) sb.Append(words3[i - 1]);
        }

        if (paisaamt == 0 && paisaconversion == false)
        {
            sb.Append("ruppes only");
        }
        else if (paisaamt > 0)
        {
            var paisatext = words(paisaamt, true);
            sb.AppendFormat("rupees {0} paise only", paisatext);
        }
        return sb.ToString().TrimEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

> Give input as number upto 999999999 the output will be in words.

```
class A
{
    string[] words0 = { "Zero ", "One ", "Two ", "Three ", "Four ", "Five ", "Six ", "Seven ", "Eight ", "Nine ", "Ten ", "Eleven ", "Twelve ", "Thirteen ", "Fourteen ", "Fifteen ", "Sixteen ", "Seventeen ", "Eighteen ", "Nineteen ", "Twenty " };
    string[] words2 = { "Zero ", "Ten ", "Twenty ", "Thirty ", "Forty ", "Fifty ", "Sixty ", "Seventy ", "Eighty ", "Ninety ", "Hundred " };
    string[] words3 = { "Hundred ", "Thousand ", "Lakh ", "Crore " };
    int[] numbers = new int[] { 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000 };
    string numstr;
    string words = "";
    int tempNum;
    int temp = 0;

    public void ConvertToRupee(int number)
    {
        numstr = number.ToString();
        words = "";
        tempNum = number;
        temp = 0;
        while (numstr != "0" && numstr.Length != 0)
        {
            switch (numstr.Length)
            {
                case 1:
                    words += words0[tempNum];
                    numstr = "";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (tempNum <= 20)
                    {
                        words += words0[tempNum];
                        numstr = "";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp = tempNum / numbers[2];
                        words += words2[temp];
                        tempNum = tempNum % numbers[2];
                        numstr = tempNum.ToString();
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Method1(3, "Hundred ");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Method1(4, "Thousand ");
                    break;
                case 5:
                    Method2(4, "Thousand ");
                    break;
                case 6:
                    Method1(6, "Lakh ");
                    break;
                case 7:
                    Method2(6, "Lakh ");
                    break;
                case 8:
                    Method1(8, "Crore ");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Method2(8, "Crore ");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        words += "Rupees Only ";
        Console.WriteLine(number.ToString() + " : " + words);
    }

    private void Method1(int n, string wo)
    {
        temp = tempNum / numbers[n];
        words += words0[temp] + wo;
        tempNum = tempNum % numbers[n];
        numstr = tempNum.ToString();
    }

    private void Method2(int n, string wo)
    {
        temp = tempNum / numbers[n];
        if (temp == 10)
            words += words0[temp] + wo;
        else if (temp <= 20)
            words += words0[temp] + wo;
        else
        {
            int twoDig = temp / numbers[2];
            int digit = temp % numbers[2];
            words += words2[twoDig] + words0[digit] + wo;
        }
        tempNum = tempNum % numbers[n];
        numstr = tempNum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: What a mess! This is just a big, useless code dump, and the code isn't even properly formatted so it is readable!