# How Convert amount to rupees and paise in words in Devexpress Xtrareport

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I want to convert the summery of devexpress report to words. I found a question 'convert amount to rupees and paise in words format in c#' here [convert amount to rupees and paise in words format in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156442/convert-amount-to-rupees-and-paise-in-words-format-in-c-sharp) But i dont know how to use the code for devexpress report to convert the number to word? Please help me how to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using the [end-user-designer](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/8546/winforms-reporting/end-user-report-designer/gui/end-user-report-designer-with-a-ribbon-toolbar) (not the visual studio), i may suggest to register [custom function](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.Expressions.CustomFunctions.Register(DevExpress.Data.Filtering.ICustomFunctionOperator--)) 'RupeesToWords' for binding expressions.
in this new function implemetation you may write your custom code.
in the XRLabel's summary expression specify the expression like this

```
RupeesToWords(sumSum(Value))
```

Comment: Please explain more. I am new.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you were to display this value in an XRLabel, you could handle the XRLabel's [BeforePrint event](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.UI.XRControl.BeforePrint) and set the Label's text to the result of the code you've already found for the conversion process.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My Total Field Label is named 'xrTableCell30' Which i want to convert to word on another Label named xrLabel5. How to write the code? Please help me.

Comment: What is xrTableCell30 bound to? Is that an aggregate field that performs a SUM of some value field in the table?

Comment: Yes xrTableCell30 bound to a data field that is performs the field's SUM. And i want to Convert it to another Label named xrLabel5. See the image [url=https://imgbb.com/][img]https://i.ibb.co/C2W37vN/Untitled.png[/img][/url] Here highlighted Name is  xrTableCell30 which perform a sum for a field. And i want to show it another Label named xrLabel5 Which is the converted to word in the image.